# Python CSV to JSON W/ Array Output

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, output

I'm trying to take data from a CSV and put it in a top-level array in JSON format.

**Currently I am running this code:**

```
import csv
import json

csvfile = open('music.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')

fieldnames = ("ID","Artist","Song", "Artist")
reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames)
for row in reader:
    json.dump(row, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

**The CSV file is formatted as so:**

```
| 1 | Empire of the Sun | We Are The People | Walking on a Dream |
| 2 | M83 | Steve McQueen | Hurry Up We're Dreaming |
```

**Where** = Column 1: ID | Column 2: Artist | Column 3: Song | Column 4: Album

**And getting this output:**

```
    {"Song": "Empire of the Sun", "ID": "1", "Artist": "Walking on a   Dream"}
    {"Song": "M83", "ID": "2", "Artist": "Hurry Up We're Dreaming"}
```

**I'm trying to get it to look like this though:**

```
{             
    "Music": [

    {
        "id": 1,
        "Artist": "Empire of the Sun",
        "Name": "We are the People",
        "Album": "Walking on a Dream"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Artist": "M83",
        "Name": "Steve McQueen",
        "Album": "Hurry Up We're Dreaming"
    },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just for Question 1, use the following snippet for your DictReader setup:

    `import collections ; reader = DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames, dict_class=collections.OrderedDict)`

Comment: 2 & 3 are unclear. Please specify expected output if you want others to help.

Comment: the import goes to your imports at the beginning and the `reader =` line is a drop-in replacement to your DictReader initialisation.

Comment: the expected output is the first thing I stated

Comment: when I put "import collections ;" on the top, and add the "reader = DictReader(csv..)" it says reader = DictReader(csvfile, dict_class=collections.OrderedDict) NameError: name 'DictReader' is not defined

Comment: The reason for the skipped field is that you have "Artist" twice in this tuple: `("ID","Artist","Song", "Artist")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright this is untested, but try the following:

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

fieldnames = ("ID","Artist","Song", "Artist")

entries = []
#the with statement is better since it handles closing your file properly after usage.
with open('music.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    #python's standard dict is not guaranteeing any order, 
    #but if you write into an OrderedDict, order of write operations will be kept in output.
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
    for row in reader:
        entry = OrderedDict()
        for field in fieldnames:
            entry[field] = row[field]
        entries.append(entry)

output = {
    "Music": entries
}

with open('file.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    json.dump(output, jsonfile)
    jsonfile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spotPy.py", line 9, in <module>
    reader = csv.DictReader( csvfile, fieldnames, dict_class=collections.OrderedDict)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.reader = reader(f, dialect, *args, **kwds)
TypeError: 'dict_class' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: oops. sorry, that was some non standard DictReader, one moment.

Comment: Note the error in OP's code where they had `fieldnames = ("ID","Artist","Song", "Artist")`. This should be `fieldnames = ("ID","Artist","Song", "Album")`.

Answer (score 7):

Pandas solves this really simply. First to read the file

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('music.csv', names=("id","Artist","Song", "Album"))
```

Now you have some options. The quickest way to get a proper json file out of this is simply

```
df.to_json('file.json', orient='records')
```

Output:

```
[{"id":1,"Artist":"Empire of the Sun","Song":"We Are The People","Album":"Walking on a Dream"},{"id":2,"Artist":"M83","Song":"Steve McQueen","Album":"Hurry Up We're Dreaming"}]
```

This doesn't handle the requirement that you want it all in a "Music" object or the order of the fields, but it does have the benefit of brevity.

To wrap the output in a Music object, we can use `to_dict`:

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump({'Music': df.to_dict(orient='records')}, f, indent=4)
```

Output:

```
{
    "Music": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "Album": "Walking on a Dream",
            "Artist": "Empire of the Sun",
            "Song": "We Are The People"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "Album": "Hurry Up We're Dreaming",
            "Artist": "M83",
            "Song": "Steve McQueen"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would advise you to reconsider insisting on a particular order for the fields since the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) clearly states "An object is an *unordered* set of name/value pairs" (emphasis mine).

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is in the wrong order. `json` is designed to convert a *single object* into JSON, recursively. So you should always be thinking in terms of building up a single object before calling `dump` or `dumps`.

First collect it into an array:

```
music = [r for r in reader]
```

Then put it in a `dict`:

```
result = {'Music': music}
```

Then dump to JSON:

```
json.dump(result, jsonfile)
```

Or all in one line:

```
json.dump({'Music': [r for r in reader]}, jsonfile)
```

#### "Ordered" JSON

If you really care about the order of object properties in the JSON (even though you shouldn't), you shouldn't use the `DictReader`. Instead, use the regular reader and create `OrderedDict`s yourself:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

...

reader = csv.Reader(csvfile)
music = [OrderedDict(zip(fieldnames, r)) for r in reader]
```

Or in a single line again:

```
json.dump({'Music': [OrderedDict(zip(fieldnames, r)) for r in reader]}, jsonfile)
```

#### Other

Also, use context managers for your files to ensure they're closed properly:

```
with open('music.csv', 'r') as csvfile, open('file.json', 'w') as jsonfile:
    # Rest of your code inside this block
```

Answer (score 0):

> It didn't write to the JSON file in the order I would have liked

The `csv.DictReader` classes return Python `dict` objects. Python dictionaries are unordered collections. You have no control over their presentation order.

Python does provide an `OrderedDict`, which you can use if you avoid using `csv.DictReader()`.

> and it skipped the song name altogether.

This is because the file is not really a CSV file. In particular, each line begins and ends with the field separator. We can use `.strip("|")` to fix this.

> I need all this data to be output into an array named "Music"

Then the program needs to create a dict with `"Music"` as a key.

> I need it to have commas after each artist info. In the output I get I get

This problem is because you call `json.dumps()` multiple times. You should only call it once if you want a valid JSON file.

Try this:

```
import csv
import json
from collections import OrderedDict


def MyDictReader(fp, fieldnames):
    fp = (x.strip().strip('|').strip() for x in fp)
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter="|")
    reader = ([field.strip() for field in row] for row in reader)
    dict_reader = (OrderedDict(zip(fieldnames, row)) for row in reader)
    return dict_reader

csvfile = open('music.csv', 'r')
jsonfile = open('file.json', 'w')
fieldnames = ("ID","Artist","Song", "Album")
reader = MyDictReader(csvfile, fieldnames)
json.dump({"Music": list(reader)}, jsonfile, indent=2)
```

Comment: You yield a standard dict. doesn't that throw away the order again?

Comment: No, the order is already destroyed. Each row is already a standard `dict`.

Comment: Yep, but see my answer - you can force it into correct order by putting the entries into an OrderedDict in order of fieldnames.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spotPy.py", line 15, in <module>
    json.dump({"Music": list(reader)}, jsonfile, indent=2)
  File "spotPy.py", line 9, in MyDictReader
    yield {k:v.strip() for k,v in row.items()}
  File "spotPy.py", line 9, in <dictcomp>
    yield {k:v.strip() for k,v in row.items()}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @AlwaysSunny - that means that at least one of the fields is missing in your data.

Comment: @MichelMüller - that's a neat idea. I'll add it to my answer, also.

Comment: @Robᵩ in the csv or the script?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny - At least one of your lines in your data file is missing at least one field.

Comment: @jpmc26 - I'm trying to avoid that by including a description of each of the issues in the prose.

Comment: @Robᵩ I may not know how to do this, but that I can promise you that is not true. There is not a field missing the in the CSV file.

Comment: @AlwaysSunny - jpmc's point is that [so] isn't intended or designed to be a code-writing service. It is intended to be a repository of useful information. Any question that is simply "please write my code for me" has no value for future generations and, in fact, makes it harder for people to find genuine questions and answers. If your goal really is to have someone write your code, there are other websites designed and intended for that purpose.

Comment: Also, @AlwaysSunny - I made changes to the code. It will probably handle blank lines better now.

Comment: @Robᵩ I spoke too soon - It uses the "ID" as a key for each object with the values being the artist, song, and album. For instance: {"Music":[{"ID": "1, songName, artistName, albumName"}, {"ID": "2, songName..

Comment: @Robᵩ I was too harsh. My apologies. My main objection was in having a fully working code block that the OP could simply copy/paste, instead of them having to work out some details themselves.